# Not able to download tapestry360-project using maven

Tags: java, maven, tapestry

I am using Hudson with maven to build one of our application, recently our repository moved to new location. When we tried to build the application we are getting the following error.

Unable to get 'com.formos.tapestry tapestry360-project:pom:1.0.0.0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

so I tried to remove the dependency in the following way but failed to build the application

```
<dependency>

<groupId>com.formos.tapestry<groupId>
<artifactoryId>tapestry-xpath</artifactoryId>
<version>1.0.1</tapestry>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>com.formos.tapestry<groupId>
       <artifactoryId>tapestry360-project</artifactoryId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>

</dependency>
```

what I am missing here. Could someone help me her in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

On maven central there is only one artifact with `tapestry-xpath` artifact.
And it has a group id of `net.sourceforge.tapestryxpath`.

See this: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.tapestryxpath%7Ctapestry-xpath%7C1.0.1%7Cjar

I believe you had erroneously gotten the group id of `com.formos.tapestry`.
If you believe that this is correct then it was probably a artifact that was hosted on maybe a local repo (nexus/artifactory) in your org.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yogesh.

You are correct that is hosted in our org repo. If I want to exclude the dependent jar what I have to do. I don want to download tapestry360-project.

Comment: Take it out from the Deps then.